# How can I make the character not going backward after collison with a bad's guy ammuntion?

Tags: motion-capture

After my main character is hit by the bad guy with ammunition, my charcter is going a lot backward. What can I do to make it go back just a little  and then come back to his place where he was hit.

Comment: try increasing characters mass or lowering bullets mass or speed